# invoice counter

Tags: php, sql

Hi I would like to do a invoice counter according to put this number in to the data base in my table named "counter". It is supposed to look like this:

```
1/2016
2/2016 
etc.
```

So I have got a problem with this line:

```
<td><input type='text' name="[counter]" value=("1/<?=date $s('Y')?>)</td>
```

the whole code look like this:

```
<?php
foreach($dane as $s):
?>
    <tr>        
    <td><input type='text' name="[counter]" value=("1/<?=date $s('Y')?>)</td>
    <td><?= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($s['inc_date']))?></td>
    <td><?=$s['sender']?></td>
    <td><?=$s['own_nr']?></td>
    <td><?=$s['letter_date']?></td>
    <td><?=$s['attachment']?></td>
    <td><?=$s['submitted']?></td>
    <td><?=$s['departaments']?></td>
    <td><?=$s['descript']?></td>

    </tr>

<?php
endforeach;
?>

</table>
<br>
```

Also I do not know if I should modify my insert:

```
$sender = $_REQUEST['sender'];
$own_nr = $_REQUEST['own_nr'];
$letter_date = $_REQUEST['letter_date'];
$attachment = $_REQUEST['attachment'];
$submitted = $_REQUEST['submitted'];
$descript = $_REQUEST['descript'];

$query = "INSERT INTO officebk (counter, sender, own_nr, letter_date, attachment, submitted, descript) VALUES('$counter', '$sender', '$own_nr', '$letter_date', '$attachment', '$submitted', '$descript')";
```

test this is a short and work perfectlly this value is not a problem, I do not want to write all the time $dane so there is $s

Comment: For better practice it's best to use proper php tags..!

Comment: Your **MySQL** is vulnerable.Learn to use [**`Prepared Statements`**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in order to secure your code.

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: Can you please quickly tell us what is `$dane` and what is the expected value of `$s`?